# how to Login Wordpress,get dashboard content and redirect to my android app?

Tags: java, javascript, php, android, cordova

So,
I am trying to make an **android app** for my client who has a **e-commerce website**. For that I have to get his **details** from his **dashboard** and somehow fetch it to graphs in the app.

For this I have to make him login, and then get his details. But till now, I am not able to get my work done. Initially I tried Login to his website through **java**, but failed. Then I tried Json Api as **wordpress** plugin , but I was told its not secure.  Then I move on to **phoneGap**, and the login part is done.

But,now the problem  is. After he login, I was not able to **redirect him to my app**. To overcome this, I thought to open page in **IFrame** and use some logic through **Js/JQuery**, But then Another thing come in my way as **"Same-Origin-Policy"**. To get through this, I tried to use **JSONP**, which till now, I am unable to use. I don't know which **PHP** file to change in wordpress or what. I am now feeling so much lost, and don't know how to get this work done.

If any one could t ell me whats the best way to do this, and if please provide with explainable snippet.. It would be very much helpful
Thankyou